# Sita Taraka Mantra?

Tags: rama, moksha, sita

I often read that the name of Rama can give liberation.
Many saints gained Moksha by repeating the name of Rama.
What about the name of Sita, is her name also a Taraka mantra?
I never read about a saint who gained realization by repeating 'Sita, Sita'.

Comment: In Telugu literature, there appeared a book "Shodashi - Ramayana Rahasyalu" ( Shodashi - the secrets of Ramayana) by  (Late) Sri Gunturu Seshendra Sarma. In that book the writer eulogises Sita as Savitri.  And, Sri Hanuman was described as as a Sadhaka, who was searching for his deity Savitri. So if you accepts that idea, the mantras applicable to Savitri, can be utilised for praying to Sita

Answer (score 4):

Her name is too powerful as Tarak mantra.
As per **lomesh samhita**

> यज्ञ दान तपस्तीर्थ स्वाध्याय आत्मबोधतः।
> कोटि संख्यं राम नाम्नि पावित्र्यं वर्तते प्रिये।।
> ततः कोटि गुण पुण्यं सीता नाम सनातनम्।
> इति ज्ञात्वा भजन्तयेतान् मुनयो नारदादयः।।
>
> > परमेश्वर सदाशिव कहते हैं – यज्ञ, दान, तप,तीर्थ, वेद अध्ययन, आत्म ज्ञान आदि कर्मों से जितना फल मिलता है उसका कोटि गुणा फल “राम” नाम से ही मिलता है और श्रीराम नाम का कोटि गुणा फल “सीता” नाम से ही प्राप्त होता है।

> > Supreme Lord Sadashiv says – The result that one gets from Yagya, charity, penance, pilgrimage, study of Vedas, self-knowledge, etc., is gained by chanting of the name of “Ram” and crore multiple times of the name of Chanting of Shri Ram is only in the name of “Sita” is received when chanted once.

Comment: “ and crore multiple times of the name of Chanting of Shri Ram is only in the name of “Sita” is received when chanted once.” <—- Wonderful, thx for posting this 

Answer (score 3):

> *ज्ञानं सीतानाम तुल्यं न किञ्चित्, ध्यानं सोता नाम तुभ्यं न किचित् ।*
>
> *भक्तिः सीतानाम तुल्यं न काचित्, तत्त्वं सीता नाम तुल्यं न किञ्चित् ॥ ६ ॥*
>
> *नान्यः पन्था विद्यते चात्मलब्धी, नान्यो भावो विद्यते चापि लोके ।*
>
> *नान्यद् ज्ञानं विद्यते चापि वेदेष्वेवं सीतानाम मात्र विहाय ॥ १० ॥*

**Translation.:**

> ***~ There is no gyana equivalent to The name of Sri Sita, There is no Bhakti equivalent to Sri Sita Nama and There is no Tattvam Equivalent to Sri Sita. The one who Recites Her name with Love, That person has got The Greatest gyana, That Person is the Greatest Bhakta and That Person Knows The True Tattvam of Vedas. That Gyana of Vedas, devoid of Love for Her name, is of no value. For Self realisation and Realising The Supreme Atma, Sita Nama is the only way, There is no other gyana or way in the vedas. Therefore, All wise ones should Recite Sita Nama.***
>
> ***(Sri Brahma Ramayana 66.9-10).***

Comment: Thx for posting this, great ! 

Comment: Almost this same shloka is again repeated in aadi ramayan aka bhushundi ramayan